# Making custom widget visible as layout element for printing in QGIS with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, print-composer

I need to make a widget visible as a layout element for printing, for a QGIS plugin I am developing.

Which of the classes do I need to extend to do this?

After some research I think I begin to discern part of the procedure to achieve my goal:

- I have to implement or extend the `QgsLayoutItem class`.
- If I extend the `QgsLayoutItem class`, I must rewrite its `draw()` method in which I will define the way the widget will be drawn in the scene.
- However, `QgsLayoutItem` has many derived classes: `QgsLayoutItemPage, QgsLayoutItemMap, QgsLayoutItemPicture, QgsLayoutItemLabel, QgsLayoutItemLegend,   QgsLayoutItemShape, QgsLayoutItemFrame` and others.

Comment: Are you aware there is existing Data Plotly plugin? Plugin website: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/DataPlotly/ Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-fz9wHEBoR4

Comment: @Miro That's a good idea!!, Data Plotly does the same procedure, I'm going to review their code

Answer (score 4):

This is a partial answer which may not be exactly what you are looking for but perhaps a pointer to get you started. I think, in theory, the solution (or at least best avenue of research) is the [QGraphicsProxyWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsproxywidget.html#details) class.

I made a few tests and achieved some, but not perfect results.
The following code snippet adds a `QWidget` with child sub-widgets to a `QgsPrintLayout` object.

```py
class TestProxyWidget(QGraphicsProxyWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QGraphicsProxyWidget.__init__(self)
        self.w = CustomWidget()
        self.setWidget(self.w)
        
class CustomWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.lbl = QLabel('A Label:', self)
        self.le = QLineEdit(self)
        for w in self.children():
            self.layout.addWidget(w)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        
project = QgsProject.instance()
mgr = project.layoutManager()
layout = mgr.layoutByName('Test Layout')
proxy = TestProxyWidget()
layout.addItem(proxy)
```

The results are shown below, but as you can see- the size of the added widget is very large and I couldn't easily work out how to resize/scale the widget. Familiar methods like `SetGeometry()`, `resize()`, `setMinimumSize()`, `setMaximumSize()` etc don't work very well here. You can resize the parent widget, but the child widgets like labels, line edits, push buttons etc. don't scale properly. I'm sure there is a different approach to controlling the size but I'm not expert in this area as I haven't worked that much with Qt graphics classes and, unfortunately I don't much time at the moment to put into research.

[image]

If you do something like [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsproxywidget.html#details) example in the docs:

```py
class CustomWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.lbl = QLabel('A Label:', self)
        self.cb = QComboBox(self)
        self.cb.addItems(['Large', 'Medium', 'Small'])
        self.pb = QPushButton('Click me', self)
        for w in self.children():
            self.layout.addWidget(w)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

CW = CustomWidget()
scene = QGraphicsScene()
proxy = scene.addWidget(CW)
view = QGraphicsView(scene)
view.show()
```

The result looks like:

[image]

Perhaps this is more of a PyQt question (which might be better asked on Stack Overflow) or if you are lucky, a QGIS developer who knows a lot more about this than I do will give you a better answer here.

Comment: Thank you very much @Ben W, I will try your proposal, you have clarified many things. However, I will wait for an answer using PyQGIS. Although, with just PyQt it could work, it is possible that it will not be accepted as a plugin in the QGIS repository because it does not meet the API standards.

Comment: @Luis Perez, you are welcome. I'm not so sure what you mean by a PyQGIS answer. If you are developing plugins I'm sure you are aware that most of Qgis gui elements are built on underlying Qt library. That includes `QgsLayout` class which inherits from `QGraphicsScene` and all `QgsLayoutItem` classes which inherit from `QGraphicsRectItem` etc. Hence my remark that your question is probably more about PyQt than PyQGIS. Anyway, I wish you the best of luck.